# How to invite friends to an event? Facebook Graph API in iPhone

Tags: ios4, facebook-graph-api

I am working in Facebook application in which I have created event Successfully, I am getting `name.place`, `start_time`, `endtime` property from api. But my problem is to send events invitation to Facebook friends, for this I am finding lot of details but that not help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you I have figured out how to create the event.  However I am not sure how to get the event id.  If you can tell me how to do that it would be great.

Bad news is it looks like Facebook has yet to implement the invite functionality using the Graph API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.invite/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

see [Inviting selected users to Facebook-Event (via Graph API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931098/inviting-selected-users-to-facebook-event-via-graph-api)

Facebook now has a graph api for inviting friends to events.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

**invited**

**Create**

You can invite users to an event by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID. You can invite multiple users by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3. Both of these require the create_event permission and return true if the invite is successful.